# Call child component inside slider in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have created this slider

> Working link :
> https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-gcgxgh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html
>
> HTML Component :

```
<div class="slideshow-container">
  <ng-container>
    <div class="mySlides animated fadeInRight">Slide 1</div>
    <div class="mySlides animated fadeInRight">Slide 2</div>
  </ng-container>
</div>
<button class="btn ansbtn" (click)="plusSlides(-1)">Previous</button>
<button class="btn ansbtn" (click)="plusSlides(1)">Next</button>
```

i have to call child component inside slider like

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let o of list; let i=index">
<child-component-1 *ngIf="i==0"> </child-component-1>
<child-component-2 *ngIf="i==1"> </child-component-2>
..
<child-component-n *ngIf="i==n"> </child-component-n>
</ng-container>
```

Getting this error on click of next button :

> ERROR Error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'className')

Any solution to call child component inside slider and fix the error, Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have this code on your stackbitz:

```
var dots = this.elem.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('.dot');
```

and there are no elements with a "dot" class in your templates.

so when you do this:

```
dots[this.slideIndex - 1].className += ' active';
```

the value of of `dots[this.slideIndex - 1]` is `undefined`;

this then gives you the error

> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'className')

To fix it, my suggestion is for you to never use a `querySelectorAll` in any of your angular code...

I will assume you have a variable in your actual component which is some sort of array which generates elements with this "dot" class.
so when clicking the button, you should manipulate this array variable, and not do a query on the template for its results.

The ideal angular flow is

1. modify the data in the component
2. all the affected templates are updated

hopefully this helps you progress!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, there is one more issue after making this `<div class="mySlides...` div dynamic inside for loop getting this error `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'style')` which is at this line `slides[this.slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";` but it should display the first slide

Comment: I'm calling this function inside `ngOnInit`  `this.showSlides(this.slideIndex);` it returns `0` slides

Answer (score 0):

Angular is not only javascript. You should re-think your carousel using variables and `[class.active]="variable"` to change the class and template reference variables and `@ViewChildren()` to get the nativeElements if was neccesary.

**Disclamer**: It's only an **uncompleted** (and possibly erroneous) e.g. of using variables in .ts that are using in the .html makes more "readable" and "friendly angular" that use a "javascript style" using document.querySelectorAll and className.replace

In briefly, if you has, e.g. some like

```
   <div #slide class="mySlides animated fadeInRight" [ngClass]="className[0]">
        Slide 1
   </div>
   <div #slide class="mySlides animated fadeInRight"  [ngClass]="className[1]">
        Slide 2
   </div>
```

You can define some like

```
@ViewChildren('slide') slides:QueryList<ElementRef>
className:string[]=[]

selectedIndex:number=0;
```

And use some like

```
slides.forEach((x,index)=>{
    this.className[index]=index==selectedIndex?'block active'
                                              :'none'
})
```

Using a .css like

```
.active{...}
.none{display:none}
.block{display:block}
```

Comment: Thanks I have updated my code can you please check why both the slides are loading on the page load